# How can I Transfer my Score Game Object from my game scene to game over scene in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have my game scene and i want to have my score be displayed in game over scene and my high score. This is my score code:

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text scoreText;
    public float scoreAmount;
    public float pointIncreasedPerSecond;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        scoreAmount = 0f;
        pointIncreasedPerSecond = 1f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = (int)scoreAmount + "";
        scoreAmount +=pointIncreasedPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a [`DontDestroyOnLoad` method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) that will keep any objects alive across scene loads.  You can add a call to that in your `Score` script.

```
void Awake() {
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}
```

Note that the GameObject must be a "root" `GameObject` (meaning it doesn't have parents in the scene). Also, be careful to not keep anything extra that you don't want alive around with it (child `GameObjects` will be left intact). The linked documentation states:

> If the target Object is a component or GameObject, Unity also preserves all of the Transform’s children. Object.DontDestroyOnLoad only works for root GameObjects or components on root GameObjects.

Comment: Its working but now my score is keep going up and i dont know how to display it now on the screen im beginner.

Comment: @GameDevEG That's because it still has an `Update()`.  You need to decide how to tell it its done counting and then make sure once it's told it's done, it stops adding.  That's a different question with a different answer though.